# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<FlatList<any>>

Tags: typescript, react-native

I get the typescript error above on my `Draglist` Component, I am using `Draglist` like this https://github.com/fivecar/react-native-draglist:

```
 type WaypointData = { id: string; name: string };
    type Props = {
      waypoints: WaypointData[];
      ...
    };
    const MapWaypoints: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
      waypoints,
    ...
    }) => {
    
      const renderWaypoint = ({ item, index, drag }: RenderWaypointProps) => {
       ...
      };
    
      return (
        ...
              <DragList
                data={waypoints}
                keyExtractor={(item: WaypointData[]) => item.id}
                onDragEnd={({ data }) => setWaypoints(data)}
                renderItem={renderWaypoint}
              />
        ...
      );
    };
```

Comment: How are you using `onDragEnd = {({ data }) => setWaypoints(data)}`? `onDragEnd`  is not a property of the list but renderItem itself. Also, it is not having any parameter in the function signature : https://github.com/fivecar/react-native-draglist